# Javascript Jump Menu not working

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function jumpto(x)
{

if (document.form1.jumpmenu.value != "null") {
    document.location.href = x
    }
}
</script>
<body onLoad="startup()">
<form name="form1">
<select name="jumpmenu" onChange="jumpto(document.form1.jumpmenu.options[document.form1.jumpmenu.options.selectedIndex].value)">
<option>Jump to...</option>
<option value="http://www.ecortes.brinkster.com/">Homepage</option>
<option value="htttp://www.google.com/">Aesop's Fables</option>
<option value="http://www.quackit.com/html/">HTML</option>
<option value="http://www.quackit.com/css/">CSS</option>
<option value="http://www.quackit.com/sql/tutorial">SQL</option>
<option value="http://www.quackit.com/database/tutorial">Database Tutorial</option>
<option value="http://www.xtechride.com">Web Hosting Tutorial</option>
</select>
</form>
```

So my javascript code is supposed to create a jump menu, but once I load the website the jump menu shows up but the links don't redirect me to the links I wrote. Any help figuring out what the error could be would be appreciated.

Comment: I tested with firefox and chrome its working fine

Comment: May help http://jsfiddle.net/wB8Xy/

Answer (score 0):

You can drastically simplify this by using some very slightly more modern HTML and JavaScript practices.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function jumpto()
{
  if (this.value) {
    document.location.href = this.value;
  }
}
</script>

<form>
  <select onchange="jumpto()">
```